# When does AngularJS custom filters are executed?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have developed a custom AngularJS filter in order to format text coming from database with break lines into 
 in html.

I have only one page where it´s used and only one line:

```
<p class="info-section-body-text" ng-bind-html-unsafe="boatSelected.comments | htmlFormat"></p>
```

The filter is working ok, but I have noticed that the filter is executed 63 times.

Why? I guess this is not the best from the performance point of view.

Comment: On every $digest, this is absolutely normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngualarJS will evaluated the directives like `ng-if` , `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, `angular filter` on UI, `{{}}`(interpolation), `ng-bind` , etc. gets evaluated on each digest cycle completion, number of digest cycle gets called all the binding of the UI level is goes through the angular digest cycle.

I believe you are using Older than angular version 1.2.(because `ng-html-bind-unsafe` has been deprecated)

If you don't want to call angular filter every time, you could use angular bindonce `::` directive which will bind data only once & never run its digest cycle.(You should have Angular 1.3+ to use this feature)

**Markup**

```
<p class="info-section-body-text" 
   ng-bind-html="::trustedHtml(boatSelected.comments) | htmlFormat"></p>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.trustedHtml = function(comments){
   //inject ngSanitize module in app & add `$sce` on controller level
   return $sce.trustedHtml(comments); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I´m using 1.0.7.

Comment: @Rober why you sticking with it,while angular has already release its stable 1.3 version

Comment: Well, I started the project more than one year ago. And, correct me if I´m wrong but I think it´s not that easy to migrate to 1.3.

Comment: yes there are some major breaking change..but digest cycle runs multiply time won't affect performance that much...if you have filter inside `ng-repeat` then it does matters a lot

Comment: All right. It´s not in a repeat. So, the conclusion is everything is normal in that version and there is nothing you should/can do. Right?

Comment: ya correct upgrade angular to latest version may add some more features two your app.. and it would be more bug freee

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74132/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-rober).

Comment: All right. I add the migration in my to-do list for phase 2 or 3 :).